# How to interchange limit and integral?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f_{n}, f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$ with the properties that,

1. $f_{n}(x)\to f(x)$ point wise for each $x\in \mathbb R;$
2. $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} \leq \|f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}$ for every $n\in \mathbb N.$

> **My question is:**
>   Can we expect 
>   $\,\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R}f_{n}(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \, dx$ ?

That is, can we expect to interchange limit and integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Fatou's lemma with $(|f_n|)_{n\geqslant 1}$, we obtain that 
$$\lVert f\rVert_1\leqslant \liminf_n\lVert f_n\rVert_1\leqslant\limsup_n\lVert f_n\rVert_1\leqslant\lVert f\rVert_1,$$
hence $\lVert f_n\rVert_1\to \lVert f\rVert_1$.

Then define $g_n:=|f|+|f_n|-|f_n-f|\geqslant 0$ and use Fatou's lemma.